# How to access JSON object using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have stored JSON to separate file `Countries.Json` inside folder called `ListofCountries` in the View.

Now I want to display these data on button click using `AngularJS`.

But I am unable to pass JSON values into my code.

Please help me.

#### Countries.json

```
{
  "Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
   {
      "Country": "UK"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="countriesCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="list-btn" value="List Data"/>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('countriesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("Countries.Json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Console the value of myData

Comment: And post the output Theb it will easy to answer, what it returns in.response.data.records ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access **`response.Countries`** not **`response.data.records`**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("Countries.json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.code = response.Countries;})
  .error(function (response) {alert("Error")})
});
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/erUdyoS1w02oVBEotQfi?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you for your demo. But currently I am getting error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` I am not getting Json file loaded. It i under shared folder in my MVC application.

Comment: which means your json path is wrong, check the path . mark if the answer helped

Comment: I will try to fix it. One more help, the Json data should display only on button click in view. So appreciated if you could add that part as well.

Comment: I do not understand one thing why this is giving me error. `GET http://localhost:62634/Test/Views/Countries.json 404 (Not Found)`. As the Json is under Views.

Comment: may be you can alter the path on the browser and see